# How to draw closed path if used the following code:

Tags: pstricks, pstricks-add

An example in PSTricks User's Guide page 34.

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-1,-1)(4,4)
\pscustom[linewidth=2pt,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray]
{
\pscurve(0,2)(1,2.5)(2,1.5)(4,3)
\pscurve(4,1)(3,0.5)(2,1)(1,0)(0,.5)
}
\end{pspicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\pscustom[linewidth=2pt,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray]{%
    \pscurve(0,2)(1,2.5)(2,1.5)(4,3)
    \pscurve(4,1)(3,0.5)(2,1)(1,0)(0,.5)
    \closepath
}
```

Comment: Same example above, how to the line is non-displayed , its mean have only the region between two curves. Help me, please!

Comment: `linestyle=none`